# Cast content of variable to pointer results in NULL after printf

Tags: c, pointers, casting, printf, low-level

I try to achieve the following: I'm having a pointer `p` pointing to an address holding again an address (this address is also a valid address). Now I want to have another pointer `pp` pointing to the address which is the content of `p`. So I'm doing the following:

```c
// Retrieve the start address
unsigned long long *p = getInitialAddress();

// Let pp point to next address
unsigned long long *pp = (unsigned long long*)(*p);

// Print address
printf("0x%llx %p\n", *p, pp);
```

This prints for example: `0x7fffedc47a70 0x7fffedc47a70` which is the desired result.

However, putting another `printf` into the code, like this:

```c
// Retrieve the start address
unsigned long long *p = getInitialAddress();

// Print
printf("%p 0x%llx\n", p, *p);

// Let pp point to next address
unsigned long long *pp = (unsigned long long*)(*p);

// Print address
printf("0x%llx %p\n", *p, pp);
```

Leads to:

```
0x7fffacea3660 0x7fffacea3680
0x0 (nil)
```

And this is not the correct result, because it **should be**

```
0x7fffacea3660 0x7fffacea3680
0x7fffacea3680 0x7fffacea3680
```

So does the `printf` alter something within the pointers or what is wrong?

**Edit: Complete code**

```c
unsigned long long* readRBP();

int main(void) {
    // Retrieve the start address
    unsigned long long *p = readRBP();

    // Print
    printf("%p 0x%llx\n", p, *p);

    // Let pp point to next address
    unsigned long long *pp = (unsigned long long*)(*p);

    // Print address
    printf("0x%llx %p\n", *p, pp);

    return 0;
}

unsigned long long* readRBP() {
    unsigned long long rbp;
    __asm__ volatile("mov %%rbp, $0" : "=r"(rbp));
    return (unsigned long long*)rbp;
}
```

This gets the rbp (Stack base pointer). The content of this pointer is the pointer to the next rbp and so on. **This** rbp is from `readRBP()` itself, the next rbp belongs to `main` and the next one after main is `0x0`, i. e. the very beginning.

Comment: You should use `%p` in `printf` format strings to print pointers.

Comment: But i'm printing contents of pointers, don't i?

Comment: Very hard to believe that this really is your code. How about a complete program that does this?

Comment: Also please don't wait for a couple of answerers to expend effort and then delete the question, like you did when you asked the exact same question 20 minutes ago.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Sorry for the deletion but the question was not very clearly defined, so i wanted to start again, normally i don't do that. Code is attached.

Comment: `main` might have a caller: some obscure routine, perhaps `_start`,  in `crt0.o`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: might be, but I don't have an explanation why the pointer / content suddenly becomes zero after using printf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value that `readRBP` returns is the base pointer for the `readRBP` function. You then call `printf` which creates its own stack frame. And that stack frame obliterates the data at `*p`.

To see that this is so you can write your code this way round:

```
int main(void) {
    // Retrieve the start address
    unsigned long long *p = readRBP();
    unsigned long long pContents = *p
    unsigned long long *pp = (unsigned long long*)(*p);

    // Print
    printf("%p 0x%llx %p\n", p, pContents, pp);

    return 0;
}
```

In other words you gather up all the information into the stack frame of `main`, before you stomp on it by calling `printf`.

Comment: So if I want to trace the stack and print this out, then I first have to gather all informations and afterwards print them. Thanks for the explanation, learned my lesson for today ;) sorry again for the deletion.

Comment: Yes, that's it. And no probs about deletion, it just took the full code to see what was special about `p`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 // Let pp point to next address
  unsigned long long *pp = (unsigned long long*)(*p);
```

The comment is wrong. `pp` does not point to the next address, but to the address obtained by casting the *content* of memory location pointed by `p`. I have no idea what `getInitialAddress()` is supposing to return, but if it is e.g. calling `calloc`, or allocating some memory with `malloc` and then zeroing it with `memset`, it is probable that the memory zone pointed by `p` starts with zero.

By the way, you are assuming that `long long` and `void*` (i.e. data pointers) have the same size. I have no idea if it is true on your system (it is false on Linux/i686 systems for instance). If you want an integral size of the same size as pointers better use `intptr_t` and include `<stdint.h>`

To explore your stack, assuming a recent GCC compiler, you might be interested in [return address builtins](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.0/gcc/Return-Address.html#Return-Address) notably `__builtin_return_address` or `__builtin_frame_address`

Comment: +1 So that the question can't be deleted  ;-)  You are quite right about the strange mixing of integers and pointers. But according to the question `*p` is non-zero.

Comment: I do want to get the content of `p` as new pointer. The original `p`comes from rbp register.

Comment: Thanks for the GCC related tip, but I wanted to do this "the hard way".